# Broken Payment Gateways

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Our customers keep calling to tell us that they cannot checkout on our website. We currently have two payment gateways;

```
Sagepay
Paypal
```

When I have tried to checkout myself, this message has appeared in an alert box:

`Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.`

Does anyone know what may be causing this and how I can fix it?

Obviously I have tried reloading the checkout page. This does not fix the issue.

Thanks

edit: we are currently using Magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error was due to the amount of checkout modules we have and a combination of clearing cache and reindexing.

The error was caused by conflicting files being loaded onto the checkout page.

Restarting Nginx fixed it for us.